# Why expect({"[\"": 2}).toHaveProperty("[\"") is not true in jest?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I would like to test that object has a property with the name `["`

In node js I can definie object "x" with property `"[\""`

```
> x = {"[\"": 2}
{ '["': 2 }
> x["[\""]
2
```

and of course

```
> '["' ===  "[\""
true
```

but when I typed test

```
expect({"[\"": 2}).toHaveProperty("[\"")
```

I received error:

```
Error: expect(received).toHaveProperty(path)

Expected path: "[\""
Received path: []

Received value: {"[\"": 2}
```

These versions also not works

```
expect({"[\"": 2}).toHaveProperty(`["`);
```

```
const p = `["`;
expect({[p]: 2}).toHaveProperty(p);
```

### Update 1

There was a hypothesis that it is because of libraries

```
"esbuild-jest": "^0.5.0",
"esbuild-node-tsc": "^1.8.5",
"jest-text-transformer": "^1.0.2",
```

But I created pure js project with only `jest@^27.5.1` installed and reproduced it

[image]

### Update 2

There was a hypothesis that it depends on the operating system. I reproduced it on Macbook Pro and Arch Linux. For node js versions 12, 14, 16.

Working workaround:

```
expect({"[\"": 2}[`["`]).toBeDefined();
```

Comment: I just tested your expect test, `expect({"[\"": 2}).toHaveProperty("[\"")` and it passed. In fact, I tested all three of your variants and they all pass

Comment: @tom which operating system do you use?

Comment: im guessing `toHaveProperty` uses json path under the covers

Comment: https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tohavepropertykeypath-value

Comment: @DanielA.White I just tried it in this Jest Codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/jest-playground-3dntr